# How to add an element to an array in karate?

Tags: karate

How to add an element to an array in karate?
I have a string array(not json array) from response and add a string element to it for next request.
I tried a lot with JS functions but with no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

```
Scenario:123

* def roles = ["role1"]
* def newrole = "role2"
* def addrolefn =
"""
function(role,roles1) {
    var fullrole = [];
    for (var i=0; i<roles1.length;i++) {

        fullrole = fullrole.push(role);
    }
    return fullrole;
}

"""
* def fullroles = call addrolefn (newrole,roles)
* print fullroles
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the [`set`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#set) keyword.

```
* def roles = ["role1"]
* def newrole = "role2"
* set roles[1] = newrole
* print karate.pretty(roles)
```

Result:

```
06:26:35.324 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] [
  "role1",
  "role2"
]
```

edit: actually I've just raised an enhancement request to add an `append` keyword to Karate. Meanwhile, this should answer all your questions and act as a workaround.

```
* def roles = null
# javascript that assigns an empty array if null
* json roles = (roles || [])
* def newrole = "role2"
# javascript to append to an array. the def void is useless
* def void = (roles.add(newrole))
* print karate.pretty(roles)
```

edit: type cast to json, and using java list api `add` method

Comment: Thanks! But what if I am appending an element to a dynamic arry whose length can be only found during run time?

Comment: I used this                                                                                                   
   * def arr = ["a","b","c"]
    * def length = (arr.length)
    * print 'length is  '+length+'    end'
    * set arr[length] = "d"
    * print arr

Comment: But getting this errorjava.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "length"

Comment: sorry.i added that

Comment: oh yeah.I marked it. Any ways , I was able to append an element for a dynamic array. But ran into another issue.My response gives me an array if there is a value in it or null if there is no value.What ever response I get I need to add an element and pass it to next response as an array.
    * set roles[1] = response[0].assignedRoles
    * print roles
    * set roles[10] = "ROSTER_EDITOR".  But the issue is some times response[0].assignedRoles is null and hence set command is failing as it's not array.This is the error 'variable is null or not set 'roles''. Please help.

Comment: This doesn't work def void = (roles.push(newrole)). Gets me error javascript evaluation failed: (roles.push(newrole)).

Comment: @Kumar112 ok fixed the example now, can you check.